# Propper way of saving an admission ticket

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, mobile

What is the state of the Art when it comes to saving an admission ticket on mobile devices?

I have a webseite and we are struggling with the problem that when a user would finish the checkout, he will find himself on an overview of all the tickets he bought.
By clicking one of the Tickets he gets the Ticketdetails with the barcode.
He also gets an email to get to the site with the overview.

But some customers asked me why is there no possibility to **save the tickets locally**.
I looked for a way to do **html to pdf**. But this is all serverside and it looks like there is no way to do it with Javascript.

So are there other options? Maybe some andoid/os onboard functions i can use to save the sites as images or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a generated pdf file from saved data on the server using javascript.

Use a premade library such as jsPDF http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/

Comment: thank you josh, not exactly what i was looking for but it is a good compromiss!